# Safari Back button not working with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular6

I am using **google Maps** in my Angular 5 application. When I call new google.maps.Map(...) in an angular component, the Safari adds an history state to the browser history. In short: If I open a page containing map, I have to click the back button in Safari twice to get back to the previous page. I used the most recent version of maps and include it using the script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHlCTJeb84dO9VEnrIqXdxpX5YNba2h7I"></script>
```

Any solutions is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No. It seems to be a safari problem..